# Unable to distribute iOS App via Xcode 13.3

Tags: xcode

I'm unable to distribute app to the AppStore via Xcode. After archiving the application, I hit Distribute App -> App Store Connect -> Upload. Then the verification process starts and after few seconds I'm getting error "**Error Analyzing App Version**" with no more details. In logs, there is not much information as well

`alertMessage='(null)', errors='()', warnings='()', infoMessages='()'`

[image]

I'm using Xcode to distribute app to AppStore for few years, never had this problem. Wondering if it could be Xcode bug or something.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- restart Xcode
- reboot computer
- revoke all certificates and generate new via Xcode
- delete all certificates from keychain, revoke them and generate new via Xcode
- delete Xcode with all it's data and reinstall from scratch

Nothing helped, still getting the same error.

I think it might be related to certificates somehow, because at the end of the log, there is message:

```
App Store Connect team IDs for account filip.****@gmail.com are (
    ********CY,
    ********VH,
    ********2G,
    ********L4,
    ********NF,
    ********ZG
)
```

But in the Xcode I can see different certificate:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WORKING BYPASS: While Apple's Hardcore Software engineers drink coffee and figure this bug out!

1. Organizer -> Distribute App -> App Store Connect -> Export -> NOW DISABLE WIFI / INTERNET (else will fail) -> Exported .ipa
2. Now use Transporter App -> Login to same account -> Add .ipa -> Upload works !

Transporter can be downloaded here: https://apps.apple.com/app/transporter/id1450874784

For more details, see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599?answerId=712953022#712953022

Comment: Thank you for your help! Looks like upload is working again, but nice to have an alternative.